# AlertManager: Loading configuration file failed

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm trying to start up Prometheus with Alert Manager using docker-compose.
I've tried all examples I've found, but the Alertmanager fails to start:

```
docker-compose up
```

. . . . . .

```
"alertmanager_1  | level=error ts=2023-12-07T18:05:07.921Z caller=coordinator.go:118 component=configuration msg="Loading configuration file failed" file=/config/alertmanager.yml err="open /config/alertmanager.yml: permission denied"
```

Here is the part of the docker-compose.yml file which defines the Alert Manager:

```
  alertmanager:
    image: prom/alertmanager:v0.23.0
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
    volumes:
      - "./alertmanager:/config"
      - alertmanager-data:/data
    command: --config.file=/config/alertmanager.yml --log.level=debug
```

[Source](https://github.com/ablx/monitoring_stack/blob/main/docker-compose.yml)

Apparently the path /config is not available in the AlertManager Pod, however all the configurations I've found use the same reference to it. Anybody can shed some light?